# Can I use a generic as a key?

Tags: c#, generics

Can I create a dictionary, where the type of the key is a generic?

e.g.

```
void addKey<T>( object value )
{
    dic.add( T, value );
}
```

Comment: `typeof(T)` will get a `Type` that represents `T`.

Comment: Thanks ta.speot.  Along a similar line, could I pass the class as a parameter?  Rather than passing an instance of the class as a parameter?

Comment: @Ginger you can pass an instace of `Type` class, which you can get by using `typeof` method

Comment: what do you mean by type is a generic?

Comment: Is this a hypothetical question or do you plan on using this in production?

Comment: Are you sure you actually want a dictionary of types to values? What are you planning to use this for?

Answer (score 3):

What about?

```
void AddKey<T>(T value)
{
    dic.Add(typeof(T), value );
}
```

Usage:

```
// the type of value is automatically detected based on usage
AddKey("sampleString");
```

You could pass type exlicity of course:

```
AddKey<BaseClass>(derriveredInstance);
```

Then, dictionary is of type `Dictionary<Type, object>`

**The drawback:**
You cannot pass instance of other (not base or not the same) class as key:

```
AddKey<int>("some string"); // compile time error
```

If you want to achieve something like this, you should take a look at other answers and pass `Type` or pass `object` as type of value.

Answer (score 1):

Just to sum up the comments:

```
Dictionary<Type, object> dic = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

void AddKey(Type key,object value)
{
    dic.Add(key, value);
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
AddKey(typeof(string), new Object());
```